# Python: zfill items in numpy array created with arange

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe containing a column 'days' with 5 entries: 492, 12374,300, 87, 90.

I wanted to take each entry and use it to build an array containing the number of days broken up into intervals of 30, so I did this:

```
intervals_list = []
for i in df['days']:
  intervals = (np.arange(0,i,30))
  intervals_list.append(intervals)
```

That worked the way I expected, resulting in 5 arrays, which stored in a new list I called intervals_list. This is the array for 300:

```
array([  0,  30,  60,  90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270])
```

Now I want to make sure all numbers in all of the arrays are 6 digits in length. I want to accomplish this by using the zfill() function to add zeroes to the left of each number until they are 6 digits in length. But I can't figure out how to accomplish this. I tried:

```
for i in df['days']:
   intervals = (np.arange(0,i,30))
   for i in intervals:
      i = str(i).zfill(6)
```

but got stuck trying to figure out how to reflect this transformation in the original arrays. I also tried performing the zfill function in the middle of the arange function, but that was also unsuccessful. Please help!!

I'm also fairly new to python, so please go easy on me!! I hope this is clear, let me know if you need any additional information :)

Comment: a). What are you trying to accomplish? and b). What is your expected output?

Comment: @Mortz I am trying to add zeroes to the left of each number in my arrays until they are 6 digits long. My expected output for each array would be something like: `array([000000, 000030, 000060, 000090, 000120, 000150, 000180, 000210, 000240, 000270)]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If suits the string data format. Then I can suggest the following: convert the intervals array to string. Apply np.char.zfill to all array. If this data is to be written to a file, then the quotes will not be visible.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

aaa = [492, 12374, 300, 87, 90]
df = pd.DataFrame({'days': aaa})
df['days'].astype(int)

intervals_list = []

for i in df['days']:
    intervals = (np.arange(0, i, 30))
    intervals = intervals.astype('str')
    intervals = np.char.zfill(intervals, 6)
    intervals_list.append(intervals)

print(intervals_list)
```

This is the array for 300:

```
array(['000000', '000030', '000060', '000090', '000120', '000150',
       '000180', '000210', '000240', '000270']
```